# What to do with knowledge about a niche product that is not yet represented on SO?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have good knowledge about a niche product that is not yet represented on SO. It has some proprietary programming languages. Since there is no help available on the internet, it could be helpful for some developers if I spread this knowledge here.
My questions:

1. Is it sensible to post, if nobody so far seems interested?
2. What is the best way to publish the knowledge?

Comment: Well, self-answered questions *are* encouraged. Still, both posts must still follow guidelines, and it's probably *harder* writing a worthwhile self-answered question. Aside from that, if the questions and answers (and users) are here, the tags will be created and more will be attracted.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure any question you post is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Make sure the question is phrased as a real question would be, rather than being an obvious set-up for a self-answer (ideally featuring a real problem you have encountered). The risk here is that some people may incorrectly interpret your Q&A pair as promoting the product in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To re-iterate and expand on what Deduplicator said in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298463/what-to-do-with-knowledge-about-a-niche-product-that-is-not-yet-represented-on-s#comment216101_298463) self answered questions are acceptable - even encouraged - so if you think you have some worthwhile knowledge to impart ask (and answer!) away.

You might find it easier to write such questions if you have an actual problem you faced and the solution you came up with, rather than trying to make something up to fit your answer. The latter could read more like an advert for a blog post than a real question.

Once you've added the question you'll need to enlist the help of a user with over 1,500 reputation to create any new tags. You can do that in chat, mentioning it in a comment on the question or, in extremis, ask a new question here on meta.